# ¿Como puedo obtener información de un usuario con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Necesito si es posible obtener la siguiente información de un usuario de mi pagina web :

1. Que navegador utiliza
2. De que país hace la solicitud
3. Que lenguaje maneja el usuario
4. Si es posible la dirección Ip

esto con el propósito de llevar un registro para estadísticas.

con respecto a la información del navegador cuando ejecuto `var nav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome');` no me genera resultados y me he dado cuenta que la propiedad `navigator` trae consigo la informacion que necesito pero no estoy seguro de estar **utilizándola** correctamente ya que usándola de otro modo como `window.navigator.language;` tampoco me genera resultado.

Comment: Hola la verdad no estoy tan seguro, pero creo que no puedes obtener esta información ya que javascript solo funciona del lado del cliente y no del servidor

Comment: por favor muestranos lo que haz investigado para poderte ayudar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es una pregunta antigua pero aquí está la respuesta (requiere JQuery):

```
var info = {
    userAgent: navigator.userAgent,
    localization: $.get("https://api.ipdata.co", function (response) {
        return JSON.stringify(response, null, 4);
        }, "jsonp"),
};
console.log(info);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte @Alvaro